# Is it possible to create window using C++/WinRT from a console application?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

When using Win32 API, it's not really necessary to have a winmain entry point in order to create a window, because we can still call `RegisterClassExW` and `CreateWindowExW`, etc. I wonder if it's possible to do so as well in creating a C++/WinRT window, since almost every example on the Internet is using template projects.

I tried to create a struct which inherits `implements<App, IFrameworkView, IFrameworkViewSource>` with all necessary functions (Initialize, Uninitialize, Load, SetWindow, Run, etc.), then call `CoreApplication::Run(winrt::make<App>())` inside `int main()`, but WinRT either complains about not having run `init_apartment()` beforehand, or shows a weird error as `WinRT originate error - 0x80070057 : 'serverName'` and that `HRESULT` is `E_INVALIDARG`, and that a `hresult_invalid_argument(take_ownership_from_abi)` is thrown. Plus, the source file created with template project doesn't even have to run `init_apartment()` first, which I couldn't really understand why.

Is it possible to create a C++/WinRT window from a console application? Thanks.

Comment: That appears to be possible. The [XAML Hosting API sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-Xaml-Hosting) might be a good starting point.

Comment: When you say console application, does that mean your application runs without app container (no AppXManifest)? If so, you cannot use CoreApplication class at all - you should use Win32 equivalents.

Comment: CoreApplication is UWP only. So it's not WinRT issue, rather fact that this part of Windows Runtime won't work in Win32 applications. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56892952/950131

Answer (score -1):

No.

> UWP console apps may not create a window. They cannot use MessageBox(), or Location(), or any other API that may create a window for any reason, such as user consent prompts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp